# Manual Process for Interactive Grid Apex 19

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am using `interactive grid` in `oracle apex 19` to insert records, now I want to manually handle `ig` using PL / SQL code but it does not insert values into the database. How can I resolve this problem. Please help me, thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you provide some of your attempts? :) A bit more of details (as a print or a code snippet) also help to better understand the problem.

Comment: Thuan, did you still need help with this or is David's answer sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it does not insert values into the database", can you please describe what you've added or changed in the Interactive Grid to do this manually?

Also, I'm curious - why are you electing to do this manually?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, example I have a table exist 2 data column: created_by, modified_by, and I have global variable :USER_NAME, I want when I insert data into the database, my created_by field will be assigned by the USER_NAME and the modified_by field will be blank, the modified_by field will only be assigned by the USER_NAME when the data is changed, so I would like to use pl / sql code to insert or update with the condition I expect, but it seems my pl / sql code doesn't work,

Answer (score 0):

Thuan, You should do this in a trigger on the table rather than trying to do it in the IG itself. In this way the columns will be populated even when data is created outside of the IG. For example (for both created by and the date performed)

```
create or replace trigger status_update_logs_biu 
  before insert or update on status_update_logs 
  for each row 
begin 
  if :new.id is null then 
    :new.id := to_number(sys_guid(), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); 
  end if; 
  if inserting then 
    :new.created := localtimestamp; 
    :new.created_by := nvl(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'),user); 
  end if; 
  :new.updated := localtimestamp; 
  :new.updated_by := nvl(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'),user); 
end status_update_logs_biu; 
/
```